# sending a command to a bot that sends a message that gets edited

Tags: javascript, message, edit

I'm trying to make a bot that edit a message when given a command. I spent 5 hours trying to work it out. This is as far I got...

```
client.once("message", async message => {
  const msg = await message.channel.send("why?");
  msg.edit("why     ");
  msg.edit("why    ");
  msg.edit("why   ");
  msg.edit("why  ");
  msg.edit("why ");
  msg.edit("why");
  msg.edit("wh");
  msg.edit("w");
  msg.edit("");
  msg.react("")
  
  });
```

I want it so when someone says "why" it looks like the goat is eating "why" and grows bigger, lol.
Sadly I can only make it run the command once with out restarting the terminal or making it spam the command.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `client.on` instead of `client.once` which only ran once as the name suggests.

---

There is also a [rate limit](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/rate-limits#header-format) on how often you can make an api call to discord.

Try the following code to give a pause in between the edits. Something look like this.

```js
async function sleep(seconds) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, seconds * 1000));
}

client.on("message", async message => {
  if (message !== "why") return;
  const msg = await message.channel.send("why?");
  await sleep(1);
  msg.edit("why     ");
  await sleep(1);
  msg.edit("why    ");
  await sleep(1);
  msg.edit("why   ");
  await sleep(1);
  msg.edit("why  ");
  await sleep(1);
  msg.edit("why ");
  await sleep(1);
  msg.edit("why");
  await sleep(1);
  msg.edit("wh");
  await sleep(1);
  msg.edit("w");
  await sleep(1);
  msg.edit("");
  await sleep(1);
  msg.react("");
});
```

---

```js
async message => {
  if (message !== "why") return;
  const msg = await message.channel.send("why?");
  ...
}
```

The function body gets executed every time a message is sent to the chat. It is important to prevent the bot from triggering itself, causing an infinite loop.

Here I added a condition so that: the bot does something only if the original message is (exactly) `why`.

You can do something more sophisticated of course, such as checking the sender, more message variants, etc.

Comment: This doesn't work. when I run the coed it just spams it in the chat. The reason why I put ``` client.once``` is to stop the bot from repeating the code over and over again. Also I want it so that anytime someone say "why" in the chat the code runs. Maybe your using a different version idk. I'm a bit of a noob when it come to coding. I'm coding with javascript in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: @sherbitfish Oh, I see you issue now. See the updated code, particularly the `if` line.

You do need the `on` instead of `once` for the script to work -- not just once.

The issue was that, since the function gets triggered every time a message pops up AND it sends another message into the channel without any kind of condition check, it loops forever and spams the channel.

Comment: @sherbitfish And to address your original idea, I don't think you can edit someone else's message (both as a normal user or a bot). You can probably come up with something similar though.

Comment: ok, so what your saying is what I'm trying to do is not possible?